# Sign up/Login Facebook + get email

Tags: facebook, authentication, sdk

On my website user click "sign up with fb" and accept application. I have no problem with getting fb's id this but...

I can't find tutorials how to do this with my customized button. I want to have something like hyperlink what makes me able to put it on my own html object or text.

I have also problem with getting users email. This require additional permission, but I'm doing something wrong cause it still not working - require only basic fb user's data all the time.

Sorry If i repeat someone's topic but many of similar are outdated yet.

Comment: I really don't understand your question regarding the Facebook button, can you try and explain it better ? What exactly do you want to do ? And about the email, also, what is the exact error ? Are you getting a null when you're trying to return the email, or denied by the access token ?

Comment: 1. I don't know how to do it using my own button 2. app still doesnt require it